# No Routes element found in React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, phpstorm

This is odd.  Following along with the [tutorial](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-routes), I'm attempting to create a group of routes.  However, the actual `Routes` element cannot be found:

[image]

The `BrowserRouter` and individual `Route` elements seem to be working fine, however.

I'm using the latest version of React Router Dom (6.2.1).  Any ideas?

Comment: `what I assume` Why are you assuming? What version is in your package-lock.json?

Comment: Uh... 6.2.1, which is what I wrote 8 words after 'assume'

Comment: No, you didn't say 6.2.1 was in your **package-lock.json**. In any case, just `npm install` or `rm -r node_modules` and then `npm install`

Comment: Deleted the `node_modules` folder and re-installed.  Problem persists.  And, yes, the version in package-lock.json is 6.2.1

Comment: "Appears to be a PHP storm issues" - sometimes you just need to restart your editor (what a terrible answer). Was that the problem?

Comment: No, because it persists in PhpStorm after a restart

Comment: as long as it doesnt crash :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might happen because of conflicting typings the IDE auto-downloads to its configuration folder for better code completion. You can remove the auto-downloaded typings from `<IDE system dir>\javascript\typings` (shut down the IDE first) and either disable `typescript.external.type.definitions` Registry key or remove `react-router-dom` from `typescript.external.type.definitions.packages` key value

The Registry can be located via: **Help > Find action** > type `Registry...`

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a PhpStorm issue.  Viewing the project in VS Code gives no errors on the element, and shows its signature and location:

[image]

Whereas the problem persists in PhpStorm even after a restart.